# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 for PostgreSQL docker image Windows Server 2022

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, containers

I have a VPS running Windows Server 2022, and I installed docker on it. I am trying to run a container which uses the postgres:14 docker image. But every time I try to run it I get:
`no matching manifest for windows/amd64`. As far as I understand this is a matching error of sorts where docker is trying to get the postgres image which supports the architecture of the host. Is there any fix for this or should I try another database technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but I managed to find a solution. Basically, you can't host PostgreSQL docker images on a Windows system. So I migrated my server to linux.